# Problema con alineación de elemento <select> HTML con Bootstrap 3

Tags: bootstrap

Tenemos el siguiente formulario para un buscador, utilizando *Bootstrap 3*.

```
<form class="form-inline" action="#" method="POST"><div class="row">
    <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
        <label for="f_campo_1" class="form-group-inline">Campo 1:</label>
        <input id="f_campo_1" name="f_campo_1" type="text" maxlength="4" value=""
            class="form-control form-control-width-small"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-inline" style="background-color: aqua">
        <label for="f_campo_2" class="form-group-inline">Campo 2:</label>
        <select id="f_campo_2" name="f_campo_2"
            class="form-control form-control-width-small"
        >
            <option value="1">A</option>
            <option value="2">B</option>
            <option value="3">C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
        <label for="f_campo_3" class="form-group-inline">Campo 3:</label>
        <input id="f_campo_3" name="f_campo_3" type="text" value=""
            class="form-control form-control-width-small"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
        <label for="f_campo_4" class="form-group-inline">Campo 4:</label>
        <input id="f_campo_4" name="f_campo_4" type="text" value=""
            class="form-control form-control-width-extra-small"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
        <label for="f_campo_5" class="form-group-inline">Campo 5:</label>
        <input id="f_campo_5" name="f_campo_5" type="text" value=""
            class="form-control form-control-width-extra-small"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button id="btn_buscar" name="btn_buscar" type="button"
            class="btn btn-default"
        >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;Buscar</button>
        <button id="btn_limpiar" name="btn_limpiar" type="button"
            class="btn btn-default"
        >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>&nbsp;Limpiar</button>
    </div>
</div></form>
```

Hemos agregado las siguientes clases *CSS* adicionales, para poder alinear los campos de dicho formulario y evitar que queden uno debajo del otro en la versión móvil:

```
.form-control-width-small {
    width: 57.6px !important;
}

.form-control-width-extra-small {
    width: 38.4px !important;
}

.form-group-inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Adjuntamos dos capturas de cómo nos queda el elemento `<select>` desalineado con respecto al resto:

Así se ve **sin** utilizar `display: inline-block;`:

[image: Así se ve sin utilizar display: inline-block;]

Así nos queda utilizando `display: inline-block;`, es decir, `.form-group-inline`:

[image: Así nos queda utilizando display: inline-block; , es decir, .form-group-inline]

Hemos pintado a propósito el `div` contenedor del `label` y del `select` respectivo con `style="background-color: aqua"` para que se note bien la desalineación.

Tenemos entendido que *Bootstrap 3* sólo aplica los estilos a los elementos `input`. ¿Es realmente así?

Comment: Hola Gabriel, no entiendo muy bien el problema. Lo mismo estoy algo espeso siendo Viernes, pero lo que quieres es que se vean todos en linea ? Yo lo he probado y, aparentemente, funciona bien: https://jsfiddle.net/fforcen/u5c4byx7/

Comment: Podrías en vez de usar `<div class="form-group form-group-inline">` cambiarlo por `<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"`>` para hacer que siempre sea 4 el tamaño (en una escala del 1 al 12) y ver si esto cambia el alineamiento del control
para hacer, que siempre esten en linea a pesar de que la pantalla quede pequeña puedes hacer mas chicos los valores de los xs y sm que son para pantallas "extra chicas (extra small)" y pequeñas (small)

Comment: @FernandoForcén no copiaste el codigo extra que tiene debajo del codigo principal

Comment: Lo he vuelto a copiar y sigue saliendo bien: https://jsfiddle.net/fforcen/u5c4byx7/1/

Comment: Lo que necesitas es el sistema de [grillas de bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed)

Comment: Vale, misterio resuelto, en Chrome sale bien, pero en Firefox no....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comenta @eezzekl tendrías que usar un diseño por columnas. Lo que quieres usar de un formulario `inline` solo te sirve para poner en linea el `label` y el `input` según la [documentación](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline). Si quieres que se mantengan uno encima del otro tendrás que usar columnas. Te dejo un ejemplo a ver si te sirve: https://jsfiddle.net/fforcen/u5c4byx7/2/

Te dejo como quedaría con el cambio:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="POST">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                <label for="f_campo_1" class="form-group-inline">Campo 1:</label>
                <input id="f_campo_1" name="f_campo_1" type="text" class="form-control form-control-width-small" maxlength="4" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4" style="background-color: aqua">
                <label for="f_campo_2" class="form-group-inline">Campo 2:</label>
                <select id="f_campo_2" name="f_campo_2" class="form-control form-control-width-small">
                    <option value="1">A</option>
                    <option value="2">B</option>
                    <option value="3">C</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                <label for="f_campo_3" class="form-group-inline">Campo 3:</label>
                <input id="f_campo_3" name="f_campo_3" type="text" class="form-control form-control-width-small" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                <label for="f_campo_4" class="form-group-inline">Campo 4:</label>
                <input id="f_campo_4" name="f_campo_4" type="text" class="form-control form-control-width-extra-small" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                <label for="f_campo_5" class="form-group-inline">Campo 5:</label>
                <input id="f_campo_5" name="f_campo_5" type="text" class="form-control form-control-width-extra-small" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="btn-group">
                <button id="btn_buscar" name="btn_buscar" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;Buscar</button>
                <button id="btn_limpiar" name="btn_limpiar" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>&nbsp;Limpiar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Fernando muchísimas gracias, quedó alineado el elemento select del buscador, hemos modificado col-xs-4 por col-xs-2, para que no queden tan espaciados los campos en la versión de escritorio.

Comment: Iremos probando con las diferentes clases de Bootstrap para cada resolución (lg, md, sm y xs) para que vaya quedando mejor.

Answer (score 0):

verifica el sistema de rejillas de boostrap, te sirve para alinear mediante divs la informacion que desees, es facil de usar y es adaptable a moviles, te recomiendo usar eso, solo es cuestion de adaptarlo a tu codigo html....

por ejemplo, si deseas crear un formulario con dos columnas y que se vea igual tanto para pantallas de escritorio como para tabletas y moviles puedes hacer lo siguiente...

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<!-- contenido de tu columna izquierda -->
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<!-- contenido de tu columna derecha -->
</div>
```

lo que significa cada uno es lo siguiente....

**col-lg-6** es para pantallas grandes (lg = large)
**col-md-6** es para pantallas medianas (md = medium)
**col-sm-6** es para pantallas pequeñas como tabletas (sm =  small)
**col-xs-6** es para pantallas aun mas pequeñas como moviles

los numeros son el ancho de la pantalla que abarcara, lo maximo es 12 y el minimo es 1, es decir, si especificas 12 abarcara el ancho de la pantalla completa, si especificas 6 abarcara la mitad, y asi por cada numero, ademas las columnas se ordenan de izquierda a derecha.... para docmentarte bien en esto, te sugiero visites la pagina oficial de boostrap en el apartado de rejillas o drids y entenderas de una manera rapida el manejo de las mismas...

saludos

Comment: Eliobeth muchísimas gracias, justamente estoy utilizando http://librosweb.es/libro/bootstrap_3/